# Создание View из Controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

ASP занимаюсь недавно поэтому прошу сильно не бить. Есть небольшое приложение на asp MVC в котором нужно вывести на страничку некоторый список. Создаю контроллер :

```
     // GET: Table
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DAL DBWorker = new DAL(_connectionstring);          
        ViewBag.ListViewTable = DBWorker.CollectionNames;
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Здесь `CollectionNames` это просто коллекция `List<string>`.  Создаю по этому контроллеру вью (правой кнопой - создать представление), генерируется такой код :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Table/Master.cshtml";
 }
<h2>Index</h2>
```

Компилируется без ошибок но при запуске в браузере падает такое исключение:

> Не удалось найти страницу макета "~/Views/Table/Master.cshtml" по следующему пути: "~/Views/Table/Master.cshtml".

В чем причина ошибки? Как вывести в ListView содержимое  View("Index") ?

Comment: Повторите создание View, убрав галочку с "Use a layout or master page". Или удалите строку `Layout = "~/Views/Table/Master.cshtml";`

Comment: @Igor галочку убрал - теперь генерируемый cshtml более полный. Добавил `asp:ListView` как теперь в `ItemTemplate` указать источник данных ?

Comment: Погодите, разве `asp:ListView` это не server-control из WebForms?

Comment: @Igor да так и есть. Его нельзя использовать в MVC?

Comment: Хм, я бы понял, если бы это работало с WebForms ViewEngine. Но у Вас же - Razor. Не знаю, никогда не пробовал.

Comment: @Igor а если нужно вывести список или таблицу каким контроллом в mvc лучше пользоваться?

Comment: Начните с html `table`.

Comment: @Igor Спасибо. а как указать контекст или источник данных для <tr></tr>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
@foreach(string item in ViewBag.ListViewTable) {
  <tr><td>@item</td></tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: то что нужно спасибо!