# Как создать WebHook MVC страницу?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Мне необходимо приложение "WinForm" для переписки в viber.
 "Webhook"  планируется для получения данных(событий) из viber, далее полученные данные будут использоваться в приложении "WinForm".

Я сделал:

1. создал проект "Веб приложение ASP.NET (.NET Framework)";
2. выбрал шаблон - "Пустой" + "MVC" + "API";
3. добавил котроллер "Контроллер MVC 5 - пустой". Имя контроллера "HookController";
4. запускаю приложение "Postman";
5. "Postman". устанавливаю запрос "POST" ;
6. "Postman". устанавливаю ссылку "http://localhost:44836/Hook";
7. "Postman". Нажимаю "SEND";
8. Результат см. картинку "-= RESULT =-";

Если я правильно понял теорию, то после выполнения действия `"Postman". Нажимаю "SEND"`, в котроллере `HookController.cs` должен выполняться метод `ViberProcess(HttpContext context)` и код должен остановиться в `точке останова`.
Этого не происходит.

Документация Viber REST API - [ссылка](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/)

**Вопрос.**
Как правильно сделать "Webhook"?

**Код `HookController.cs`**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

//
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;

namespace WebAppl1.Controllers
{
    public class HookController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Hook
        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

         [HttpPost]
        // [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public void ViberProcess(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                Stream s = context.Request.InputStream;
                // Stream s = Context.Request.InputStream;
                // or  Stream s  =  HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
                s.Position = 0;
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
                string jsonText = reader.ReadToEnd();

                // Other code that converts json text to classes
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // .....
            }
        }

    }

}
```

[image: Рисунок 1]

[image: Рисунок 2]

[image: Рисунок 3]

**Обновление_1**
Переименовал метод  `ViberProcess` в `Index`.
**Результат:**
`Ошибка сервера в приложении '/'.
Для данного объекта не определено беспараметрических конструкторов.
Описание: Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Изучите трассировку стека для получения дополнительных сведений о данной ошибке и о вызвавшем ее фрагменте кода.

Сведения об исключении: System.MissingMethodException: Для данного объекта не определено беспараметрических конструкторов.

Ошибка источника: 
Необработанное исключение при выполнении текущего веб-запроса. Информацию о происхождении и месте возникновения исключения можно получить, используя следующую трассировку стека исключений.`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как создать ASP NET MVC страницу, а не WebHook.

Comment: Вы создали контроллер. Контроллер не обладает указаным функционалом, его нельзя "посмотреть" напрямую. Для "рендеринга" (отображения страниц) используется вью (View).Ну где-то так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709733/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-view-%d0%b8%d0%b7-controller-mvc

Comment: За пример я брал инструкцию - [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDrMLWCOYIk)

Comment: Я вам указал на вашу ошибку. Смотреть ютуб не буду. Возможно вы не дошли до шага создать вью. Следующий шаг - создать вью (представление).

Comment: как минимум 2 ошибки: 1) Переименуйте `ViberProcess` в `Index` или настройте роутинг 2) функция `ViberProcess`должна возвращать какой то ответ. Ну и в догонку, как вы собрались подисываться на хук? Вы внутри WinForms приложения веб сервер хотите поднять?

Comment: @tym32167 `1) Переименуйте ViberProcess в Index или настройте роутинг`
Обновил вопрос. См. "Обновление_1"

`2) функция ViberProcess должна возвращать какой то ответ.` 
 Я понимаю... 
 **Вопрос-1.** Это условие чтобы код работал? 
 Я меня сейчас задача, чтобы выполнялся метод, а он не работает... 
 Если я вас правильно понял.... 
 
 Хотя... исходный метод 
 `public ActionResult Index()
 {
            return View();
 }`
 реагирует на `POST` запрос.
 Только как правильно его сделать... ?

Comment: @tym32167 `Ну и в догонку, как вы собрались подписываться на хук?`

Если я правильно понял, то я это уже сделал [ссылка](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/viberapi-i-get-the-error-message-quotbad-receiver-idquot)
Но возникла проблема как получать ответы от `Viber`///

Comment: @tym32167 `Вы внутри WinForms приложения веб сервер хотите поднять?` 
Я пока смутно представляю как это будет выглядеть.. Я полазил по интернету, вроде что-то похожее было...

Comment: @tym32167  Мне нужно чтобы через интерфейс `WinForms` можно было контактировать с пользовтелями `viber` 
и забирать аналитику(кто пописался, "сообщение отправлено", "сообщение получено", "сообщение прочитано" и т.д. ).
я предполагаю использовать библиотеки: 
1. `viber.bot` - ссылка [ссылка](https://github.com/edanila/viber.bot)
2. `Viber-Webhook-Api` - ссылка [ссылка](https://github.com/kutsoff/Viber-Webhook-Api)

**Вопрос-3.** Вы работали с API `Viber`?

Comment: По моему вы не понимаете, что делаете. Вы пытаетесь писать веб сервер, но не ясно, как вы этот сервер планируете хостить. Ссылка на webhook-api у вас ведет на проект веб сервера.

Comment: также вы берете метод, который работает, и меняете его сингатуру, меняете возвращаемое значение на void, имя на `ViberProcess` и зачем то добавляете параметр `HttpContext context` и думаете, что оно взлетит. Этого не будет, почитайте про то, как писать действия контроллера и вы поймете, почему у вас не работает и как надо, документации и примеров полно

Comment: вот есть [интересный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46114112/receiving-custom-webhooks-in-a-windows-form-application), вот [репа](https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-Asp.Net-WebHooks), откуда можно начать, я бы от этого отталкивался.

Comment: @tym32167
`1) Переименуйте ViberProcess в Index или настройте роутинг`
Вы правы... Я плохо понял ваш ответ... 

Наверное формируйте ответ.
Прилагаю "болванку" для ответа.

В ASP.NET имеется роутинг - файл `RouteConfig.cs`.
По умолчанию там `"Имя контроллера"/['index']` 
где `index` подставляется как дефолтное значение.
 `routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }`

Comment: @tym32167 В результате при отправке запроса на localhost:44836/Hook
ищется контроллер HookController и Index метод с аттрибутом [HttpPost].
В результате метод должен выглядеть так
`[HttpPost]
public string Index()
{
   string jsonText = "";           
   Stream s = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
   s.Position = 0;
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(s);
   jsonText = reader.ReadToEnd();
   return jsonText;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, я не знаю, зачем вам именно это решение и почему вы считваете весь входящий поток как строку, а не как JSON объект, но вы ваш код можете поправиь аот так

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public string Index()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

И вы сможете возвращать переданную на сервер строку

[image: ...]

Подробей о там, как начать программировать с asp.net mvc вы можете узнать [тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/) или [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started)

Comment: `я не знаю, зачем вам именно это решение и почему вы считваете весь входящий поток как строку, а не как JSON` мне сейчас просто для начала изучения "за рычаги подёргать", а потом буду к нормальному виду приводить...