# Как отправить данные из WebHook в WinForm?

Tags: c#, asp.net, viber-api

Мне необходимо приложение WinForm, которое будет клиентом для Viber.
Я создал WebHook, который принимает POST запросы от сервера Viber.
POST запрос содержит JSON.
WebHook создан из шаблона ASP.NET Framework "Пустой" + "MVC".

**Вопрос.**
1. Как сделать, чтобы если WebHook получает POST запрос, то полученный JSON отправлялся в "WinForm"?
2. Если данное решение не приемлемо, то как правильно организовать передачу данных из WebHook в WinForm в рамках другого решения?

Код **HookController.cs**

```
 using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;

namespace WebAppl.Controllers
{
    public class HookController : Controller
    {
        // *** Original code ***
        // GET: Hook
        //public ActionResult Index()
        //{
        //    return View();
        //}

        [HttpPost]
        public string Index()
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас экшн контроллера не имеет никаких входных параметров:

```
public string Index()
```

Поэтому вы работаете с сырым запросом. Судя по [документации](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#webhooks) туда POST'ом приходит некоторый json

Поэтому вы можете описать это следующим образом, чтобы сразу работать с объектом, а не с json:

```
public string Index([FromBody] ViberRequest request)
```

И использовать ваш request как вам нужно - json будет преобразован в объект.

Класс будет что-то вида:

```
public class ViberRequest
{
    public string send_name { get; set; }

    ...

}
```

(Класс ViberRequest можете получить при помощи онлайн-сервиса https://app.quicktype.io/#r=json2csharp )

По-хорошему пришедшие сообщения стоит сложить в базу, откуда их и будет доставать по мере необходимости ваш клиент (ваше winforms приложение). Просто пришедшие при помощи вебхука сообщения приходят единоразово, перезапустите своё приложение - и ничего из ранее полученных сообщений не увидите.

В вашем же варианте вы читаете сообщение и отдаёте его обратно серверу вайбера, а оно ему не нужно, ему достаточно просто получить HTTP 200 OK как подтверждение что вы обработали сообщение. (При неуспешных попытках типа 500, 503 сообщения могут быть переотправлены - точно не уверен за вайбер, но вот телеграм хук так точно делает несколько раз)

Нужно же понимать, что на одном хосте вы вряд ли сможете держать запущенным winform приложение и asp.net сайт - только разве что в случае если у вас машина будет торчать в интернет. (Для вебхука нужно указывать адрес сети в интернете). Поэтому какие-то варианты типа "кидать event в winform приложение и перерисовывать по приходу события интерфейс будут скорее чисто теоретическими.

---

Вопрос-3.

> ... ему достаточно просто получить HTTP 200 OK ... 
>   Как это сделать?

Просто отдайте пустую строку.

Вопрос-4.*

> Если проект (`WebAppl` + `WinFor`)(см. скрин вопроса) располагается в
>   одном решении (на компе Win7),  то как заупстить `WebAppl` из
>   `WinFor`? Т.е. запускаю `WinFor`, а `WebAppl` запускается
>   автоматически

Нда. Кратко: никак, ознакомьтесь с [вариантами развёртывания asp.net core веб-приложений](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/?view=aspnetcore-2.2), там такой версии нет. Либо IIS, либо self-хост, либо облако azure... но проблема даже не техническая - а архитектурная.

Я пожалуй дополню ответ, поскольку видно что вы не понимаете именно как это будет работать в системе.

Сервер вайбера при получении какого-то сообщения (допустим с сотового) может обратиться к какому-то публичному серверу стоящему в интернете. Но к одному. И к - публичному. Ваше приложение winforms скорее всего будет стоять за NAT провайдера, а если вы пишете winforms приложение, которое будет развёрнуто на нескольких машинах одновременно - то тем более нельзя полагаться на то, что у вас машина с веб-сервером будет на том же месте, что и машина с winforms-приложением(приложениями).

(Не, я чисто гипотетически знаю, что вы можете пробросить порты и выставить машину с winforms в интернет, дать ей DNS-имя - но я не уверен, что вряд ли этот то, что вы хотите сделать. А может и хотите - но вы как-то пока идёте наощупь и сами вряд ли понимаете, что именно в хотите)

Итого, у вас будет некоторый сервер в интернете, к которому будет обращаться вайбер. Там же будет и SQL-сервер, куда вы сохраните сообщения.

А уже машина/машины с winforms будут ходить к этому серверу за данными для отображения. При этом есть два варианта:

- вы можете сделать другое webapi для получения данных
- вы можете использовать connection string и идти напрямую к базе

Более подробно пока не могу сказать. Вы спрашиваете такие крупные куски знаний, что кратко ответить проблематично, кроме того - везде стоят архитектурные выборы, которые вы должны сами сделать и быть готовы к тому, что выбор наугад потом окажется неверным и придётся переделывать.

Comment: Просто почитайте [предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/998459/179763) автора, там все это уже есть.

Comment: @tym32167 действительно, вижу, что многие моменты уже обсуждались. Тем не менее, похоже, что топикстартер всё ещё не понимает, как это будет работать:  как зарегистрировать хук, где будет расположен слушающий сервер.

Comment: Очевидно, что не понимает. Об этом говорит факт наличия данного вопроса :)

Comment: @AK
Мне нужно отойти, потом отвечу подбробнее... 

**Вопрос-1.** 
`public class ViberRequest`
Где размещать?
В проекте `WebAppl` или `WinFor`?


**Вопрос-2.** 
`... пришедшие сообщения стоит сложить в базу ... ` 
Какая логика?
Логика:
1. В метод `public string Index()` добавить выражение, которое будет сохранять в 
Я правильно понял ваше предложение?
Из базы получить изменения можно только если пользователь обратиться из интерфейса `WinForom` к базе данных?

Comment: @AK
**Вопрос-3.** 
`... ему достаточно просто получить HTTP 200 OK ... `
Как это сделать?


**Вопрос-4.** 
Если проект (`WebAppl` + `WinFor`)(см. скрин вопроса) располагается в одном решении (на компе Win7), 
то как заупстить `WebAppl` из `WinFor`?
Т.е. запускаю `WinFor`, а `WebAppl` запускается автоматически

Comment: @eusataf Давайте так: можете не особо всматриваться в то, что я написал про автоматический разбор json запроса, у вас этот момент минорный (код который вам дали в прошлом вопросе тоже рабочий) а основное непонимание архитектурное, поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос 1 можно особо не давать: в любом проекте, который будет доступен в контроллере, я выносил бы подобное в ViberApi, которое бы подключил к проекту с контроллером. Ну или просто в проекте контроллера описал бы - тут многое зависит от того, что и как понадобится впоследствии.

Comment: @AK
Спасибо за ответ. Буду переваривать. 

**1.** Моя цель предварительно ознакомится с принципами работы `Viber Api`, ASP.
Для этого я предолагаю разместить на локальном компьютере приложение 
 WinWorm(интерфейс для пользователя), 
 которое будет взаимодействовать с SQL-сервер и ВебСервер(для взаимодействия сервером `Viber Api`).
 Всё размещается на одном компьютере и используется одним пользователем.
 Приложение открою для интернета с помощью `Ngrok`.
 
 Я правильно мыслю? 
 Буду признателен, если выскажете свои замечания по поводу такого подхода.

Comment: @AK
**2.** Торопился... Сделал ошибку в ворпросе. Дублирую.
**Вопрос-2.** `... пришедшие сообщения стоит сложить в базу ...` 
Какая логика? 
Логика: 1. В метод `public string Index()` добавить выражение, 
которое будет сохранять JSON из POST запроса сервера Viber в БД(SQL-сервер).
**Вопрос-2.1** Я правильно понял ваше предложение? 
**Вопрос-2.2** Из базы получить изменения можно только если пользователь обратиться из интерфейса WinForom к базе данных?

Comment: @AK
**Вопрос-5.**  С учётом вышесказанного (п.1 текущего комментария) ответ на `Вопрос-4` остаётся прежним. 
Или можно как-то по простому?
Я конечно изучу вашу ссылку, 
Вот тут вроде без заморочек [ссылка](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-Consume-Web-API-in-Windows-Forms-Application-using-C.aspx)
Хотя у меня данный пример не работает.
Получаю ошибку `"Метод "PopulateDataGridView()", строка "string json = client.UploadString(apiUrl + "/GetCustomers", inputJson);". 
Ошибка: 
"Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (500) Внутренняя ошибка сервера.`

Comment: Если вы просто осваиваете технологию, то вы можете настроить в Visual Studio запуск нескольких проектов одновременно. Это будет вам вам первый вариант запуска двух приложений одновременно. Второй вариант: вам нужно поднять локально IIS и задеплоить веб-приложение в IIS, соответственно вариант два будет останавливать/запускать IIS. Третий вариант - написать службу ОС Windows и в ней разместить службу. Например, использовать [TopShelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf). С ngrok не сталкивался, но допустим это сработает, хотя я бы просто пробросил порт на роутере.

Comment: @AK  `этот веб-сервер должен иметь IP в сети интернет и резолвиться DNS-серверами.` Разве `Ngrok` это не выполняет? 
Я создал приложение ASP. С помощью `Ngrok` сделал его открытым в интернете.
Т.е. от `Ngrok` получил `http` и `https` ссылки. 
При переходе по этим ссылкам была видна страница html моего ASP приложения. 

Мне это нужно для предварительного рассмотрения, а не на длительную эксплуатацию.

Comment: @AK не заметил, что обновили комментарий...